# Правило CSS. Стили для элемента

Tags: css

Возможно ли указать стиль для элемента:

```
<li class="new" id="lib"></li>
```

Так, чтобы `id` и класс были в связке, т-е `#new.lib {style}`.

Чтобы правило сработало только при наличии у элемента `li` идентификатора ID и класса.

Answer (score 3):

Да  `li#new.lib {...}`, но зачем? ID это и так уже уникальный атрибут, поэтому достаточно будет `#new {...}`.